# AngularJS - Access node/express session information

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I am working on a node application that uses Express and Passport for authentication and authorization, and all of that is working properly.  I am stumped, however, on how I would get the current user (set as req.user by Passport) in my Angular controllers.

I want to be able to do normal things like displaying the username in a header/navigation bar (among other things), and I am currently doing this using the Jade view engine, but I don't like mixing using the Jade view engine for some "data-binding" and Angular for others.

Now, I do know that I could easily make a call to an api endpoint in node that returns req.user as JSON, but that seems like an ugly solution, as I would be hitting that endpoint everytime there is a page load (this is not an SPA).

So my question basically is this: Can I get the currently logged in user in my Angular views so I can do all my data-binding client side instead of some server side (with the Jade view engine) and some client side with Angular?

Note: No code snippets because everything actually is working as intended, I'm just hoping for a better alternative than what I currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using "ng-init" on the DOM that defines the ng-app, that is a server side data printed in Express (assume Dust template). Below is a simple example of this:

```
    <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl" ng-init="logged_in_user = {req.user}">
      <div...
      ...
    </body>
```

then you can access the logged_in_user in your homeCtrl, as "scope.logged_in_user"
Hope this helps..

-Bhaskara

Comment: I think that's pretty much what I'm looking for.  I do have a root scope leftover from a previous iteration of this app when I was trying a bunch of different things, and I think this would be the perfect place for something like this.  Marking as answer unless I run into an unforseen issue. :)  Thank you very much!

Comment: Was hoping I could edit my previous comment.  I did get this working with a little bit of playing around, and I might expand on it a bit, but I have the basis working, so thank you once again! :)

Comment: @JamesMcConnell although you can use `$rootScope`, a better place for this would be a Service, which you can inject into controllers where necessary and access private APIs.