# Accessing Session values in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am unable to access the session values which is set by node.js in Angular.js controller. I am using the Express framework. How to resolve it? Here is my code.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: '1234567890QWERTY',
    cookie: { httpOnly: false }
     }));
//setting the values
cookies.set('username',username);
req.session.username=username;
```

Comment: AFAIK it can't since session is stored in server side, CMIIW. Try different approach like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919942/angularjs-access-node-express-session-information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you want to do something like show the username in your angular app. As I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728069/963195), the hard part to Angular is not thinking about what data the server has, but thinking about data the server should provide to the browser via API.

My general model is to have the angular page start up without any data and have a low-level controller invoke a service (say `AuthenticationService` or `IdentityService`) that requests relevant data from the server, e.g. `HTTP GET /api/identity`. That will return a block of JSON that the page can then store in that low-level controller. Any deeper controller can then access the identity (or whatever) data loaded in that first request.